# Can not access JavaScript function inside HTML (main is not defined)

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to access "main" javascript function inside HTML, and getting reference error says "main" is not defined. Can't see what is missing.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>dataset</title>
        <script>
            function main(){
                ....
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="main()">
        <h1>dataset</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried it and it works. Maybe you have a typo in your definition and so the browser won't recognise `main`? Can you post the actual definition of the function?

Comment: Code works just fine, just remove the '...' from your function(main) content and try writing some logic in it.

Comment: Rename the name function, it may be used. Also add `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  //the event occurred
})`

Comment: when I am using your code with .... inside main function I am getting error ..Can you please try with alert("Hello") inside main function .. It worked for me

Comment: Well, I assumed he didn't use the code _exactly_ the way it's typed here, of course ...

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, just remove the '...' from your function and add `alert('test)` OR `console.log('test)` for testing

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>websites dataset</title>
        <style>
        img{
            height:100px;
        }
        </style>
        <script>
                function main(){
                  alert('test');
                }           
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="main()">
        <h1>websites dataset</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The script has to be defined within the body of the HTML for it to be referenced.

So just rearrange your code to accommodate:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>websites dataset</title>
        <style>
        img{
            height:100px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="main()">
        <h1>websites dataset</h1>
        <script>
                function main(){
                ...
                }           
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Scripts can be placed in the <body>, or in the <head> section of an HTML page, source : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp